# Ruby on Rails Capistrano to update the code without deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

Am looking for Capistrano Geek to reduce the Deployment time & process.

everyone knows how the capistrano is working, its always Clone code to the target server and keep the code as release directory & create a symblink to current directory.

Here am looking for Git pull request, in ROR if I made any changes like Changing the Caption, updating text means I dont want to deploy the whole application again.

I simply need to update the code which has minimum changes

For that I have to use Git pull to update the changes & Git pull is not working in the Capistrano

I directly ran git pull in the release path I got error only.

Could anyone has solution for this pls post & my sample code is show below.

```
desc "Update the deployed code."
 task :update_code
   execute "/usr/bin/git pull origin #{fetch(:release_path)}")
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Capistrano uses `git archive`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb#L67) to create the release copy of the repo. This does not include the `.git/` directory, so further `git` commands will not work.